# Why is std::numeric_limits::digits10 is one less for int types?

Tags: c++, digits

Why `std::numeric_limits<Any Int Type>::digits10` is one less than it can be?

For example, `std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::digits10 == 2`, but `100` consists of three digits.

Or, `std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::digits10 == 18`, but INT64_MAX (`9'223'372'036'854'775'807`) consists of 19 digits.

Comment: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10) says: "any number with this many decimal digits can be held by the type". Since 999 cannot be represented by `int8_t`, the answer cannot be 3.

Comment: @KerrekSB Ha, got it. Thanks!

Comment: what a confusing const...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10` is the *guaranteed* number of digits in a sense that a number with that many digits can be represented in type `T` *without causing overflow or loss of information*.

E.g. `std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::digits10` cannot be 19 becuase `9'223'372'036'854'775'808` has 19 digits but is not representable in `int64_t`.

In general case such guaranteed value of `digits<N>` will always suffer from this "one less" discrepancy on platforms where `digits<N>` is not a power of `radix` used for internal representation. In non-exotic cases `radix` is 2. Since 10 is not a power of 2, `digits10` is smaller by 1 than the length of the max value.

If `std::numeric_limits<T>` included `digits16` or `digits8` these values would've been "precise" for radix 2 platforms.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of numeric_limits::digits is as follows:

The value of std::numeric_limits::digits10 is the number of base-10 digits that can be represented by the type T without change, that is, any number with this many decimal digits can be converted to a value of type T and back to decimal form, without change due to rounding or overflow.

This means that int8_t is 2 digits because there are some 3 digit numbers you can't represent with an int8_t (i.e. 999)